# Weird issue, putting session_start() causes pages not to load

Tags: php, session

All pages that have session_start() on the page have suddenly stopped loading and it's been working for years like this. Even the host is unsure of what to do, looking for advise.

A sample test page with the following code also failed:

```
error_reporting(1);
if(!$_REQUEST['disable']=="yes")
{

session_start();
}
echo "hello";
```

If I call the page without passing the parameters ?disable=yes the page doesn't load, it just hangs processing

The site is hosted along with 2 other sites on the server, the other 2 don't have any issues, it's just this one site that has all of a sudden started acting like this [no code has been changed on the site for 2+ months now].

Comment: Check whether the session directory, defined by `session.save_path` is still writable.

Comment: Any errors? What do the logs have to say about this?

Comment: Also make sure that you're not hitting the limit on your disk space. If you haven't made any changes and it just suddenly isn't loading any more, it's possible that you don't have enough disk space left to write a new session file.

Comment: There are no errors or logs, the page just gets stuck in the processing stage and nothing happens. Also @Pushpesh is there any code I can write to check if session directory is still writable?

Comment: @BenD I checked disk space, more than sufficient space available

Comment: `if(!$_REQUEST['disable']=="yes")`? Do you mean `if (!isset($_REQUEST['disabled']) || $_REQUEST['disabled'] != 'yes' )`? Your sample code's logic is faulty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the issue!

And guess what, it's not even related to sessions! Although quite surprising that mysql can cause such issues with sessions.

So what happened:

I have a master DB server and a replication slave DB set up. Most of the pages in my server were trying to connect to the slave and if the slave failed, it would connect to the master. However, for some strange reason [which I haven't figured yet], the mysql_connect to the slave db just hung without timing out and this in turn, for some odd reason, wouldn't allow any other page which had session_start() to load!

Now I am not sure as to why this would have such a side-effect on all other pages but I had to disable my slave server, routing all my queries only to the master and then cleared my browser cache before I could access the site again.

So a mysql_connect to a db that doesn't work or cannot be connected to [and with the mysql_connect not timing out], it can cause issues with any other page on your server from loading - even a simple 4 line page that I have put in my question above, a page that doesn't even call the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sessions are not enabled.

use `phpinfo();` to output the php settings to screen and look in the session table closer to the bottom. It should say `Session Support => enabled`

Comment: It's enabled. In fact there are 3 websites on the same server, the other 2 websites don't have any issues, it's only this 1 particular site that suddenly has started showing these errors

Comment: Just throwing out possibilities. Do the php files in this website have different owner than the other websites? possibly it could be a folder permission error in the session folder.

Comment: also look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679616/session-start-hangs-the-server

Comment: I don't know how to verify the permissions, I've asked my host. As for the other solution, dont think applicable in my case from what I understood of what's mentioned there.