# PHP : session_start()

Tags: php

Whenever I try to use `session_start()` *[ at the very top of my file as it should be ]* it gives me the following: This webpage is not available, which otherwise is not displayed when I do not use sessions. 
I would really appreciate any help.

Here is only a simple code for demonstration:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: run a `phpinfo()` and verify the SESSION table, near the end of the page, check for `Session Support => enabled`

Comment: @Phiter i' ve checked it and its enabled

Comment: You use Chrome? If you have another browser, try to check with it. You can also delete cookies in Chrome and retry.

Comment: @fusion33k i've checked with other browsers as well.. and it is still enabled

Comment: Check webserver and php logfiles.

Comment: Do you use mysql on your page ?

Comment: @coke. You see «Here is only a simple code for demonstration». Have you tried also to load this exact simple code?

Comment: @fusion3k i've copied that code just to demonstrate that its not working for me

Comment: Try to run your example code as @fusion3k recommend you :)

Comment: @coke. Is it your server reachable? If is it and if you want, you can write  the url and us can load-it. Just to define if the problem is server or client related.

Comment: @coke Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2679649/1190700

Comment: @fusion3k its not reachable :/ have no idea whats the problem but anyway thank u for the help :)

Comment: @Math thank u for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

i think It's the permission issue on the session folder. The start_session() failed to create session.
to get the location of the sessions folder use the function sys_get_temp_dir():

```
<?php

  echo sys_get_temp_dir();
```

after you found the location, if you are using Linux and Apache,
you should change the group of the folder that you have founded

sudo chgrp www-data /the folder that you got from sys_get_temp_dir()/

Answer (score 0):

Get or set  your session path [session_save_path()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php)

```
  session_save_path();
```

Maybe session is required permissions

Try it for permission

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /yoursessionpath
```